# Is my answer inappropriate for this question about binary addition with Strings

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm having a polite disagreement with another SO user about the appropriateness of a an answer I gave to a question.

The question and my answer can be viewed at the two links repsectively.

Q: [Add two strings containing binary numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18934675/260633)
My answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934746/260633

Note: I'm still updating the answer in response to feedback, for reference, the link below
is the answer in the state it was when this question was posted.

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18934746/2

Is my answer inappropriate. I feel that a correct, testable answer should be the goal of any question, and that it met the requirements presented.

If the answer is inappropriate or not useful, I'll happily take it down.

Comment: "inappropriate" is a strange word to use. I doubt it's going to help the OP much as you seem to have ignored what they're doing, but it may well help others in the future - leave it up there but clarify that it's the standard way of doing this if the OP wasn't writing their own.

Comment: The question ask why the OPs code isn't working. Your answer never mentions why.

Comment: Your answer is equivalent to telling someone learning about the various sorting algorithms to simply use the built-in sort functionality of a container or standard library. While that is ultimately what they might want to do (and therefore a decent answer) it does not help them with what they are trying to learn now. I'd leave the answer in place, but perhaps would even extend it to first address the actual problem they're facing.

Comment: @user814064 then it should be closed

Comment: @Cole Johnson Why. He's asking how specific functions in java work. The answer is equivalent to giving someone a a train ticket who wants to learn to ride a bicycle. There's not even a single word about why train travel is better. Just a ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether appropriate is the right word but you didn't answer the person's question.

This is not the person's question:

> Anyway, I'm in a middle of an exercise that asks me to build a method
>   that get two strings containing only the characters "0" and "1" from
>   the user and returns one string of them both (binary)combined

The person's question is the statement with the question mark at the end of it.

> But it doesn't return the right result. Do you mind help me out here?

He's wondering why his code does not work.

The things that are missing from your answer:

1. An answer to the poster's question.
2. Any rationale or reason why his methodology was wrong.
3. Any rationale or reason why an experienced java programmer would do what you suggested. Is it faster, clearer, less error-prone, etc.?